# How to insert/update/delete records from tables without primary key using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to connect to a **third party** database.

Now I have to insert some records into a table that have no primary key set and I get this exception:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on 'Table (the_table)' because it has no primary key.*

How can I solve this? should I use `ExecuteCommand` to avoid this exception?

Comment: Is there a unique column in the table ?

Comment: @tschmit007 Yes, there is a unique column, but isn't set as PK

Comment: use it (that is declare) as a pk in the EF model

Comment: @tschmit007 yes! it works! please answer the question so I can accept it.

Comment: but if you use the unique column as a PK, linq to sql prevents updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the unique column as a PK in the EF model.

Comment: in my DBML file I set the unique column as PK for the table and now it works! Thank you.

Comment: but if you use the unique column as a PK, linq to sql prevents updating it.

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteCommand` will give you a better performance as you can delete all records in one query.